# VB: How do I create nested classes?

Tags: vb.net, class

I would like to write a *nested class* into an existing class of my own. But I can't find how because I have no idea how this is really called.

What do I mean by nested class? With a table `dt` from the `DataTable` class, I can write `dt.Columns.add()`. `Columns` would be property of the main class and `add` would be a method from a nested class.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not a nested class, it's simply a class. The Columns property is of the type `DataColumnCollection` that has a public method called `Add`. To build your own in a similar fashion it would simply be:

```
Public Class MyFirstClass

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Dim _second As New MySecondClass()
    Public Property Second() As MySecondClass
        Get
            Return _second
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As MySecondClass)
            _second = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Public Class MySecondClass
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub MySecondClassMethod()
        'Do something
    End Sub
End Class
```

This would then be called in some other class or functionality like:

```
Dim x as New MyFirstClass()
x.Second.MySecondClassMethod()
```

Comment: Thanks Joel! And if want to group properties, is it the same logic? Say that to access the `carrot` property, I have to go through `plants.vegetables.carrot`.

Comment: I would think of carrot as a class personally, but yes the concept is the same. `Plant.Vegetable.Carrot.Color = Color.Orange`.