# if class y is inside of class x, why isnt instance of class y inside of instance?

Tags: vb.net, oop, inner-classes

I'm writing a VB.NET class library for a grocery application i'm writing but I think I have a misunderstanding of how OOP works in VB.NET. I had thought that if `class x` was in `class y`, that *instance* of `class x` would also be in in *instance* of `class y`, but apparently that is not the case. How would I set it up to be able to access an instance of `class x` via `class y`? Also why isn't instance x in instance y?

(Update: What i mean is this)

```
Public Class y
    Public Class x //class inside of class
    End Class
End Class
Public Class Form1
    Public Sub Form1_Load(<params>) Handles Me.Load
         Dim yinst As y = New y()
         Dim xinst As x = New y.x()
         MsgBox(yinst.xinst) //instance inside of instance
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please post an example of what you mean when you say _class x was in class y_

Comment: Thats called a nested class,  X is not the same as Y because Y can be much more than just a wrapper around X.  `X` for example does not contain another `X`.    The `New x()` code wont work in a real app, it would have to be: `New y.x()`

Comment: how do I add instances of x under y?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12261968/vb-how-do-i-create-nested-classes

Comment: some additional official .net [recommendations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9f3ty7f%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work (except for the message box call), but I'm not sure if this is what you really want.

```
Public Class y
   Public Class x '//class inside of class
   End Class
End Class

Public Class Form1
   Public Sub Form1_Load(<params>) Handles Me.Load
        Dim yinst As y = New y()
        Dim xinst As y.x = New y.x()
        'MsgBox(yinst.xinst) '//instance inside of instance
   End Sub
End Class
```

If you want an instance of y to have an instance of x, then I think you want something like this:

```
Public Class y
    private x As New x 'A reference to an instance of x
    Public Class x 'class inside of class
    End Class
End Class
```

...or better:

```
Public Class y
     Private _x As New x 'A reference to an instance of x
     Public Class x 'class inside of class
End Class

    Public Property InstX As x
        Get
            Return _x
        End Get
        Set(value As x)
            _x = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

In either of these forms, x will be reachable with `Dim xinst As y.x = yinst.InstX`.

Comment: Can you explain the `Public Property` block? I have never seen that structure before

Comment: Otherwise, Thank you very much

Comment: Instead of declare the instance variable as public, you can make it private and then expose it indirectly using the property. This gives the object's code a chance to inspect values, modify them, run code, etc in response to setting or getting data.

Comment: Before your comment I thought all variables declared in a class's global scope were properties. Is there a VB.NET Class Structure tutorial out there?

Comment: does the `_` in `_x` have any significance, or did you just do it that way by convention?

Comment: @Aang Its a convention to indicate a private member-level variable that is used to maintain the data for a public property of a class. It has no special effect in terms of how the compiler behaves.